# Jboss ESB Services on multiple machines

Tags: jboss, jms, soa, esb

I am very new to jboss esb and trying to learn and configure a new startup project.

The project deals with using ESB as the backbone and multiple applications connecting to it for Intg.

I have gone through each of the examples provided and was able to reach to a certain level, but little confused on few other stuff.

1) Use ESB to be hosted on machine1 (consumer) and process this message (it works).

2) Now the sender and ESB consumer are on 2 different machines. The sender is unable to locate/load the esb consumer.

I believe you might have enough experience working through this, so would you know how do I get this resolved.

you can reach out to me on hitjain_83@hotmail.com

Your help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

This will probably help:

https://community.jboss.org/thread/146623